# Tau Function expressed as a Cauchy Product

Tags: modular-forms, cauchy-product

I'm reading about the Ramanujan tau function, defined in my lecture notes by

$q \prod_{n=1}^{\infty} (1-q^n)^{24} = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \tau(n) q^n$.

[Wolfram](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/TauFunction.html) provides the identity

$\tau(n) = \frac{65}{756}\sigma_{11}(n) + \frac{691}{756}\sigma_{5}(n) - \frac{691}{3} \sum_{k=1}^{n-1} \sigma_5 (k) \sigma_5 (n-k)$,

where $\sigma_k(n)$ is the divisor function, which it says has been found via the Cauchy product.

Unfortunately I have not seen this identity anywhere else, and I can't seem to see it worked through anywhere! I'd love to say I got anywhere trying it myself, but I am going to have to ask for help. Can anybody give me a hand??

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do you know [Eisenstein series](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eisenstein_series)? Look for $E_{12}$ and $\Delta$ expressed in terms of $E_4$ and $E_6$, then eliminate $E_4$.

Comment: You can look page 11 of "Sujatha R. Iwasawa theory and modular forms[J]. Pure and Applied Mathematics Quarterly, 2006, 2(2)."  There is the full proof.